# jquery empty div class and add new content

Tags: jquery

originally I want to empty div class when there is "extraordinaire" matching in the url. because I am using multiple template for different domain. and the module_menu is refering to a dynamic menu. I have to delete this menu and here is the code and it is working fine:

```
    <div class="navigation-v" id="smoothmenu-v">
    {module_menu,1216740}
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    if(location.href.indexOf('extraordinaire') >= 0) {
        $('.navigation-v').empty(); 
        // clear value then add new menu content inside
    }    
});
</script>
```

then I try to add a new menu into the empty div, and i have the following code, but it is not working, i tried .appnd(), .html() but none of them work, i think the problem maybe the comma in the module_menu that breaks the logic, but im not really sure. please help. thank you.

here is the code:

> ```
> <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
>
> <script type="text/javascript">
> $(document).ready(function() {
>     if(location.href.indexOf('extraordinaire') >= 0) {
>         $('.navigation-v').empty().html('{module_menu,1271722}'); 
>       // clear value then add new menu content inside
>     }    
> });
> </script>
> ```

Comment: Did you tried `.append()`?

Comment: does this give you what you expect? `location.href.indexOf('extraordinaire') >= 0` is `extraordinaire` in the url?

Comment: Please tell us what is going wrong and we may be able help. "It doesn't work" could mean anything.

Answer (score 1):

use replaceWith method, it will replace the new div with existing div

```
$('.navigation-v').replaceWith('<div class="navigation-v" id="smoothmenu-v">{module_menu,1271722}</div>');
```

Or use html method as follows

```
$('.navigation-v').html('{module_menu,1271722}');
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks fine. I've only improved the append a bit to make it readable.

```
$('.navigation-v').empty().append(
    $('<div/>', {
        'class': 'navigation-v',
        'id': 'smoothmenu-v'
    }).html("{module_menu,1271722}")
);
```

Comment: I quite like creating objects in this style but i do not agree it is more readable than a string exactly how you would write it in html... more pleasing, but not more readable.

Comment: I agree. At least, for me, it is :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('.navigation-v').html('<div class="navigation-v" id="smoothmenu-v">{module_menu,1271722}</div>');
```

Comment: thanks, but it is not working, i think the problem maybe the comma in the module_menu that breaks the logic, but im not really sure.

Comment: do you enter `if` loop or try inserting simple text in div

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the .html() function, use the .append() method.

```
$('.navigation-v').append('{module_menu,1271722}');
```

I find this to be a cleaner method if all you need is to insert content inside the div and not actually change its ID or other attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Thought id add my 2 pence as your code is technically fine. (you probably didn't mean to put another div with the same class in as the containing one but hey) the issue is does the current page you are on have `extraordinaire` in the Url?

Here is a fiddle to prove it works http://jsfiddle.net/tL3PN/1/

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if(location.href.indexOf("fiddle") >= 0) {
        $('.navigation-v').empty().html('{module_menu,1271722}');
    }    
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="navigation-v" id="smoothmenu-v">Hello</div>
```

As you can see `Hello` is replaced because in this case `fiddle` is in the current pages URL...

Comment: yes i have "extraordinaire" in my url

Comment: @wanghaipeng but as you can see the fiddle works. something else is wrong with your code. is `{module_menu,1271722}` supposed to be replaced with some other text?

Comment: i would like to replace the menu id from "1216740" to "1271722", this is why i first empty the div then try add it back, the {module_menu, 1271722} is a whole block with a comma, and I just dont know why it wont work

Comment: i've tried .append() and .html(), but still no luck :(

Comment: @wanghaipeng out of interest what is your menu built with? does `{module_menu, 1271722}` convert into some text from somewhere else? Is `1216740` the ID of a string or object you are trying to put into a template that makes the menu dynamically?

Answer (score -1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {   
        $('.classname').html('<div> content goes here </div>');
    });
</script>
```